# EXC_BAD_ACCESS when using Xcode 4

Tags: xcode, ios4

I upgraded to Xcode 4 last week and I am trying to run a program which I developed in Xcode 3...

In my app, I have a navigation toolbar with a table. when i click any cell of the table, it takes me to my next view and in the navigation bar a button comes up which should take me to my previous page. When i press that button to go to the previous page, the following error pops up..

int retVal = UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, nil); where the error is Thread 1: Program received signal : "EXC_BAD_ACCESS".

it works perfectly when i run it on xcode 3 but shows this error on xcode 4..

would someone be able to help me out?

Thanks...

Comment: I figured out where I was going wrong.. before I release a view or anything else, I assigned it to null.. this solved my problem... so for the views, before releasing it, i assigned it to null and for other variables i assigned it to null in  - (void) viewDidUnload method...

Comment: UPDATE : that did not solve my problem... so still searching for where I went wrong... As told by many others, do not assign it to null other than in the dealloc method... that does not solve the problem...

Comment: UPDATE : I do not know if this would be the cause of my problems.. but by mistake while I was installing the new SDK, I overwrote the previous one by installing it in the same location ( did not know this).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make sure that you don't have any memory leak. To verify if you have memory leak or not in  xcode 4 go to the Product menu and click on the analyze and check if there are any memory leak warning and if there are fix them, hopefully that should solve your problem

Comment: thank you for the reply.. I did that already and fixed all the issues that popped up but still the program crashes for me.. I am yet to figure out what exactly the problem could be...

Comment: hmm interesting, i was facing the same problem and as soon as I did that, the app started like boom, some more inside into your code is required to debug more then in that case

Comment: Refer this beauty full tutorial http://www.techpaa.com/2012/03/finding-app-crash-and-fixing-them-easly.html

Answer (score 2):

Turn off Correction in the Inspector.

I had the same problem, and it has something to do with the autocorrection within the simulator.

Comment: In Xcode select the TextField:
Open the Attributes Inspector > Correction > No